# Here a problem on pointer arithmaic subtraction into an array

Tags: c, pointers, subtraction

The output  of `printf("%d ", *(q-3));` and `printf("%d ", q-p);` should result into `16` and `3` but compiler printing `7` and `4` instead.

can you explain it to me how is the calculation going on.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a[] = {5, 16, 7, 89, 45, 32,23,10};
    int *p = &a[1];
    int *q = &a[5];
    printf("%d ", *(p+3));
    printf("%d ", *(q-3));
    printf("%d ", q-p);
    printf("%d ", p<q);
    printf("%d ", *p<*q);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `q = a + 5` so `q - 3 = a + 5 - 3 = a + 2` and therefore `*(q - 3) = a[2] = 7`. C array indexes are 0-based, meaning the first element of `a[]` is `a[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will answer your question. have a look at the output and read comments added in code to understand better.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a[] = {5, 16, 7, 89, 45, 32,23,10};
    int noe = sizeof(a) /sizeof(a[0]);
    int count = 0;
    
    int *p = &a[1]; 
    int *q = &a[5];
    
    while(count < noe)
    {
        printf("&a[%d] = %p and value there is %d\n", count,&a[count],a[count]);
        count++;
    }
    /* pointer arithmetic: when you subtract/add integers from pointers 
     resultant size = size of datatype * number of movements
     in this case, size of datatype(int) = 4 , number of movements = 3 so i.e, 12
     bytes will be moved backwards (since substraction) */

    printf("address  yeilding (q-3) =%p and value at *(q-3) = %d\n",(q-3), *(q-3)); 
    printf("address  of q = %p and address of p = %p and  q-p = %d\n",q,p, q-p); // 4
    return 0;
}
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
&a[0] = 0x7fffeb35b600 and value there is 5
&a[1] = 0x7fffeb35b604 and value there is 16
&a[2] = 0x7fffeb35b608 and value there is 7
&a[3] = 0x7fffeb35b60c and value there is 89
&a[4] = 0x7fffeb35b610 and value there is 45
&a[5] = 0x7fffeb35b614 and value there is 32
&a[6] = 0x7fffeb35b618 and value there is 23
&a[7] = 0x7fffeb35b61c and value there is 10
address  yeilding (q-3) =0x7fffeb35b608 and value at *(q-3) = 7
address  of q = 0x7fffeb35b614 and address of p = 0x7fffeb35b604 and  q-p = 4
```